# Add value to the column in Datatable using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

MyTable contains **Col1** which has Duplicate values.

How to select Duplicate Values from my table using Linq

My table is as follows

Table 1

```
Col1      Col2   Col3
 1         A
 1         B
 1         C
 2         D
 2         E
 3         F
 3         G
 4         H
```

I want to add values to the third column i.e **Col3** in My Table

My code  is

```
 var MYValues= from c in MyTestTable.AsEnumerable()

                                 select (new { Col3 = c.Field<string>("MyCol")}).ToString();
```

MYValues contains "3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

So I want my Final table to be something like

```
Col1      Col2   Col3
 1         A       3
 1         B       4
 1         C       5
 2         D       6
 2         E       7
 3         F       8
 3         G       9
 4         H       10
```

How to add this to table??

Please help

Comment: Can you make another table to show how you want your result(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, you say you need duplicate items,
But answering your second query

```
for(count = 0; count < dataTable.Rows.Count; count++)
    dataTable.Rows[count]["Column3Name"] = myValues[count];
```